# "What would you do if it were possible" Part of Speech

Tags: subjunctives, conditionals

> "What would you do if it were possible"

Is it appropriate to call this a "second conditional" AND a past subjunctive?

Comment: **were** really is a subjunctive, but it's definitely not past. For all other verbs we use backshifting to indicate a hypothetical statement, but backshifting does not indicate past when used this way, and it would be misleading to call it past.

Comment: @JavaLatte It is traditional, though, to call it "past subjunctive". (See also https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-past-subjunctive-in-english ) I agree that this is potentially misleading, and there is also a strong case for not calling it subjunctive at all (see BillJ's answer).  However, when we backshift, we still refer to the resulting form as "past tense".  Tense is a matter of form (or inflection), not of time.  If I say "I go to Paris next Wednesday", I'm using the present tense to refer to a future event.

Answer (score 1):

> *What would you do if it were possible?*

Yes, it is a conditional, but it's not really a subjunctive construction.

This "were" is called 'irrealis', a special mood form instanced solely by "were" with 1st or 2nd person singular subjects.

It's an untidy relic of an earlier system, and some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite (past tense) "was" instead.

Note that the term subjunctive is better used for those clauses headed by a plain form verb, as in "It is vital [that I **be** kept informed]".

Comment: Note that many people (such as the author of The Oxford English Grammar) do indeed consider this to be subjunctive. It is usually called the "past subjunctive" or "subjunctive II". (I'm sure that BillJ knows this, but I just want to point it out for others.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan  Mood is an inflectional category of verbs. Unlike Latin, for example, English has no inflectional mood system – it was lost in earlier stages of the language. The residual ‘irrealis’ represents the sole remnant of an earlier inflectional mood system in English. To claim that Present-day English has a subjunctive mood is to perpetuate a myth – ESL students deserve better.

Comment: Yes, there is a variety of views about whether to call "subjunctive" and "imperative" moods. (And even interrogative sometimes! Though I certainly draw the line there. :) ) That's all I was trying to note.

Answer (score 0):

> "What would you do if it were possible"
>
> Is it appropriate to call this a "second conditional" AND a past subjunctive?

The sentence as a whole is a *conditional sentence*.  It is also an example of what EFL/ESL teaching materials call the *second conditional*, because the "if" clause has a verb in the simple past and the result clause has "would" followed by a bare infintiive ("would do").  The canonical form of the second conditional is along the lines of "If I were ..., I would ..."; this sentence is simply an interrogative variation of that.  Note that the numbered conditionals are used solely in EFL/ESL teaching; the major comprehensive grammars produced by and for native speakers don't mention them.

The term "*past subjunctive*" is used in some grammars to refer to the use of the past tense in conditions (such as "were" in "if it were possible").  (The term "past" refers to the *form*, not the time period being referred to.)  However, since the "past subjunctive" is only distinct for one verb and even then only in the 1st and 3rd persons singular, and since many speakers replace "were" with "was" even here, it makes more sense to think of "were" as an isolated irrealis form.